# Where to place the fontfile for the FFmpeg drawtext-Filter?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, drawtext, fontconfig

I'm using the precompiled FFmpeg-Android by Bravobit (via gradle: `implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'`; based on WritingMind's) with the intention of drawing the current timestamp/location onto a .mp4 file. I am completely new to FFmpeg and have started with Android Studio a few months ago.

**Information:**

- IDE: Android Studio
- OS: OSX 10.13.5

**My problem:**

I don't know whether the fontfile needs to be in the Application path on my Phone, in the Android Studio directory or just on a location on my MacBook (so it gets compiled when running the application).

Basic FFmpeg commands (-version, ...) are working, but I can't seem to figure out where I have to place my fontfile.

My current command is as follows:

```
-i /path/to/video.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontfile=/users/shared/fonts/arial.ttf:text='Hello World' /path/to/output.mp4
```

I've tried a lot of variations and always received to following errors:

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
>       [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xecbfd420] impossible to init fontconfig
>       [AVFilterGraph @ 0xec9cc140] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=/users/shared/fonts/arial.ttf:text=Hello World'
>       Error reinitializing filters!
>       Failed to inject frame into filter network: Unknown error occurred
>       Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
>       Conversion failed!

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this to work?

Comment: Change `arial.ttf :text` to `arial.ttf:text`.

Comment: My bad. That was just a mistake while writing this question.

Comment: I have the same problem with this command: String[] cmd = {"-y" , "-i","input.mp4,
                            "-vf",
                            "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf: text=\'Stack Overflow\': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2",
                            "-acodec:",
                            "copy",
                            "output.mp4"};